# value assignment to matrix not working in r

Tags: r

Let's hypothetically say I have "dating scripts" from 5 people that consist of 20-25 items each. I have all of these items stacked in one column. What I need to do is to create another column that contains a number for the position that the item was in (1-25) in the respective person's list. I have written a function to do so, but something is going wrong. Using `print()` I know that everything is working up until the storage of the item positions. Below is a reproducible version of my code. Please let me know if you know where I have gone wrong.

```
script_length <- data.frame(matrix(20:25, nrow = 5, ncol = 1)
managed_data <- data.frame(matrix(1, nrow = 5, ncol = 1))

parts_before <- 0
rows_before <- 0
include_freq <- 0

 rowsb4 <- function(participant) {

      parts_before <- participant - 1

      if(parts_before == 0) {
        rows_before <- 0
      }

      if(parts_before != 0) {
        for(i in 1:parts_before) {
          rows_before <- rows_before + script_length[i,1]
        }
      }
      rows_before <- rows_before
      return(rows_before)        
    }


count_to_20_smth <- function(participant) {

  rows_before <- rowsb4(participant)
  include_freq <- script_length[participant,1]

  for(i in 1:include_freq) {
    managed_data[(rows_before + i), 1] <- i
  }

  return(managed_data)
}



    item_placement <- function(participant) {

      parts_before <- 0
      rows_before <- 0
      include_freq <- 0

      for(participant in 1:nrow(script_length)){

        parts_before <- participant - 1
        include_freq <- script_length[participant,2]

        # base case for if doing first participant
        if(parts_before == 0) {

          for(i in 1:include_freq) {
            managed_data[i,1] <- i
          }

        }

        if(parts_before != 0) {
          count_to_20_smth(participant)
        }
      }   
    }
```

Comment: Hi Amanda, Could you provide a sample input and expected output for your data? I can't fully understand what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I would insert a `browser()` in your functions and execute them. This will start the debugger and you can step through each function to diagnose the issue.

Comment: @Rohit each participant has a script_length ranging from 20-25. In my example above, participant #1 has 20 script items and participant #2 has 21 script items. My function is supposed to, in this example, list 1-20 followed by, 1-21, etc. resulting in a singular column that is the length (total script items, aka `sum(script_length)`). The reason why rows_b4 is important is because the 20-something numbers need to be properly stored at the correct index in `managed_data`. It is only working for the base case of `parts_before == 0`; the numbers 1-20 are correctly inserted into `managed_data`.

Comment: @AmandaDavis, are you trying to do this : `r<-20:25;unlist(sapply(r,function(x) 1:x))` ?